# Не работает export и import в nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, импорт, export

Что было опробовано:

1. Из справки перепробованы все варианты, но ни один не работает. Здесь же я размещу только 1 из вариантов, которые как и все не работают.
2. Я пробовал также помещал файлы проекта внутрь папки node_modules. Не работает.
3. Я пробовал указывать полный путь до файла. (указывал файл как с расширением, так и без расширения, а также обосабливал как ", так и в ' скобки) Итог один - не работает.

Что было установлено: nmp install express

Сам пример:

```
// jsHidden.js:
var Foo = function() {
    console.log("!!!");
}
module.exports.Foo = Foo;

// index.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var m = require('./jsHidden');
m.Foo();

// Ошибка: Unexpected token 'export'
```

// В общем то все скопировано под копирку с разных источников и синтаксически ошибок нет раз у всех это работает. Но почему же у меня это не работает? Надо установить дополнительный модуль какой то ? Хотя ни о  каких модулях дополнительных нигде не говорится.

Не думаю конечно, что здесь смогут помочь, но посмотрим.

Comment: а где файл `jsHidden.js`? Правильно `npm`, а не `nmp`. Как запускаете? Какая нода? Говорите о `export` и `import`, а сами используете `require`...

Comment: Опечатка. Вообще он был в разных местах... Там где папка node_modules и файл index.js они все в одной папке, потому что я уже от тупости отталкиваюсь...  На VPS такой подход работал отлично. А на локалке не работает.... По всей видимости нужен какой то дополнительный модуль-компилятор, но только не babel - уж слишком дорого он обойдется. Дешевле будет все смешать в один файл чем городить костыли с babel. Я использовал все варианты. Я уже написал об этом и импорты в т.ч. (просто способов больше 20 будет точно, не буду же я это все описывать).

Comment: Ошибка: Unexpected token 'export' — судя по ошибке, может быть устаревшая Node.js, которая пытается распарсить файл с новым синтаксисом ES модулей (или парсит их как CJS почему-то).

Comment: vsemozhebuty, Тоже так думал, но проверив версию.. Она у меня 12+ сомнения отпали... Вероятно стоит попробовать пооткатывать версии ноды или обновить ее... Может я скачивал не стабильную версию... но это сейчас проверю...

Comment: Непонятно просто, почему в примерах у вас CommonJS, а ошибка такая, будто где-то файл с ESM.

Comment: Ну как видите тут кода в несколько строк. Мой мозг сломался и я не могу ответить на этот вопрос...

Comment: А если убрать или закомментировать `const express = require("express");
const app = express();`, что-то меняется?

Comment: Я убирал, но нет. Да и смысл его убирать. У меня app задействованно просто. Сейчас еще пара минут и посмотрим на 14 версию ноды...

Comment: Сейчас обновил ноду до 14 - заработало...